# Orders of products of permutations

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, co.combinatorics, geometric-group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, $n\gg p$ not divisible by $p$ (say, $n>2^{2^p}$). Are there two permutations $a, b$ of the set $\{1,...,n\}$ which together act transitively on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and such that all products $w(a,b)=a^{k_1}b^{l_1}a^{k_2}...$ of length at most $n$ satisfy $w(a,b)^p=1$ (here $k_i,l_i\in {\mathbb Z}$)?

Update: Following the discussion below (especially questions of Sergey Ivanov, here is a group theory problem closely related to the one before.

Is there a torsion residually finite infinite finitely generated group $G$ such that $G/FC(G)$ is bounded torsion? Here $FC(G)$ is the FC-radical of $G$, that is, the (normal) subgroup of $G$ which is the union of all finite conjugacy classes of $G$.

For explanations of relevance of this question see below (keep in mind that the direct product of finite groups coincides with its FC-radical).  Note that if we would ask $G$ to be bounded torsion itself, the question would be equivalent to the restricted Burnside problem and would have negative answer by Zelmanov.

If the answer to any of the two questions above is negative for some $p>665$, then there exists a non-residually finite hyperbolic group.

Comment: The number 665 in the comment below, no doubt, arises from the negative solution of Burnside's problem. Can you, please, edit the question and indicate, as a motivation, what you know about the connection? 

Comment: It does not apply to the bounded Burnside problem. Together with the solution of Burnside problem it applies to some other group theory problem. Unlike the bounded Burnside problem, this is about *finite* groups. In fact group theory motivation is misleading here because I do not see how to apply any group theory to this problem. It may be just a combinatorial Olympiad-type problem about graphs or it may belong to a completely different area of mathematics. So in this case, I think, the less you know about Burnside problems the better. 

Comment: Does the hypothetical construction have to work for *all* large enough values of $n$, or would it suffice to give a sequence $n_i \to  \infty$ for which the construction works?


Comment: It would be great to have a sequence $n_i\to \infty$, and pairs $a_i,b_i$ (for a fixed $p$). It would be even better to prove that such a sequence does not exist.  

Comment: The condition that $a,b$ act transitively on a set with at least $n$  elements is equivalent to the condition that the group they generate has order at least $n.$ One direction is trivial and the other direction is given by the Cayley construction (action on itself by left multiplication). Thus the question can be reformulated as follows: does there exist a 2-generated group of large order $n>2^{2^p}$ in which all short words (length at most $2^p$) have order dividing $p$?

Comment: Where does the length bound $2^p$ come from? Does it just stand for "some large number", or is there something special about this constant?


Comment: First of all there is a condition that $p$ does not divide $n$. Otherwise there is an issue with the restricted Burnside problem. If $p\not | n$, then any permutation of order $p$ has fixed points, which can be used. So your reformulation is not "equivalent". As I said, I am sure that any straightforward group theoretic approach to this problem will fail. This is a problem about graphs and, possibly, random walks on them. For example, a conjecture is that for every $a,b$ of order $p$ the random product of length $p^2$ of $a,b$ does no have order $p$ with positive probability. 

Comment: Sergei, yes, $2^p$ is a "large number depending only on $p$", and $2^{2^n}$ is "an even larger number". 

Comment: Sergei, in fact one can assume that there are counterexamples for, say, $p=673$, any choice of "$2^p$" and any choice of "$2^{2^p}$". Then there is a double indexed sequence of pairs of permutations $a_{i,n}, b_{i,n}$, such that these are permutations of $\{1,...,n\}$, acting transitively, and every word of length $i$ in $a,b$ is of order $p$. I was thinking about passing to some kind of limit, as in the notion of graph limits from combinatorics or asymptotic cones, produce some infinite object which then can be studied by some "infinite mathematics". 

Comment: If, for every number in place of $2^p$, there is a sequence of examples with $n_i\to\infty$, then a diagonal procedure yields an infinite example for the bounded Burnside problem, isn't it?


Comment: Sergei, You mean taking a subgroup of the factor-group of the Cartesian product of the finite groups generated by $a_{i,n_i},b_{i,n_i}$ modulo the direct product? Yes, the subgroup generated by the sequences $(a_{i,n_i}),(b_{i,n_i})$ in that factor−group should be an infinite group of exponent $p$ if $i\to \infty$. Then one would want to apply Zelmanov's solution of the restricted Burnside problem but the factor-group is not necessarily residually finite, unfortunately.

Comment: No I meant the following type of an argument. Suppose $B(2,p)$ is finite, say it has $N$ elements. Then it can be defined by finitely many relations (e.g. by the full multiplication table). Each of these relations follows from some finite set of the original relations (those of the form $w^p=e$). Thus there is a finite set of relations of the form $w^p=e$ implying that the group has no more than $N$ elements. Once you replace your $2^p$ by the max length of these relations, you cannot get $n>N$.


Comment: In any case, yes, positive answer implies existence of infinite 2-generated groups of exponent $p$. But first of all the answer is supposed to be negative, at least I hope so. And second, the infinite Burnside groups of exponent $\ge 665$ do exist. So this observation does not give much. I was thinking about a proof that infinite Burnside groups do not embed into the factor-groups I described above. It is similar to the restricted Burnside problem. But there is no linearization even in the case of $p$-groups, and there is no Hall-Higman theorem reducing everything to the case of $p$-groups. 


Comment: @Victor: I just noticed your claim that "The condition that a,b act transitively on a set with at least n elements is equivalent to the condition that the group they generate has order at least n. " That is not true because $S_{n-1}$ is a non-transitive subgroup of $S_n$. 

Comment: It's a pity this question (the 2nd one) is so much hidden (with a title seemingly unrelated). I actually once spent a few hours within your questions trying to find it, without success.

Answer (score 6):

If $p=2$, then your condition  on words of length at most $2^p$ implies that $a$ and $b$ have order two and commute.  Therefore they generate a group of order at most four.  So, they together cannot act transitively on a large set.

Comment: The question is for all $p$'s. The first "interesting" p is $>665$. The expected answer is "no" for all $p$. 

Comment: To be more precise: the case $p\le 3$ is easy. I do not know how to do the case $p=5$. The first case interesting for applications is $p=673$. 